# se puede usar el operador || para validar letras (chars) en un "do while loop"?

Tags: java, validación, caracteres

me gustaria saber porque este codigo de aqui funciona (siendo identico al segundo excepto por || ).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char letra; //declara variable

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //crea objeto Scanner

    //do while loop para validar la letra (loop si pones letra c)
    do{

      System.out.println("ecribe una letra que no sea c: ");
      letra = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }while(letra != 'c' );


  }
}
```

y este codigo no.(repite el loop infinitas veces si importar que letra pongas)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char letra; //declara variable

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //crea objeto Scanner

    //do while loop para validar la letra (loop si pones letra c o f)
    do{

      System.out.println("ecribe una letra que no sea c o f: ");
      letra = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }while(letra != 'c' || letra != 'f'); // aqui el problema. agregue 
    // el operador || y ahora no funciona la validacion (no acepta ninguna letra
    // y sigue repitiendo el loop)


  }
}
```

les agradeceria mucho si me dieran una idea de done podria modificar mi codigo, O de si hay maneras mas eficientes de hacer esto.

Comment: Intenta con `&&` en lugar de `||`.

Comment: wow, gracias si que era una solucion bastante simple jeje .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque el código No es identico, la lógica de la comparación es algo muy distinto:

El operador  `||` (`OR`) valida si la primera parte de la entrada es verdader **o** la N-sima es positiva

Los posibles resultados son los siguientes:

```
v1 = true || true // true
v2 = true || false // true
v3 = false || true // true
v4 = false || false // false
```

Si vemos tu código usando la misma lógica tenemos algo así:

```
haz {
    //Leer entrada
}mientras(
     entrada no sea 'c'
     o entrada no sea 'f'
)
```

Si lo probamos con datos obtenemos algo así:

```
entrada = 'c';
boolean continuar = 
( 'c' no sea 'c' ) //false
o ( 'c' no sea 'f' ) //true
// false || true = true;

entrada = 'f';
boolean continuar = 
( 'f' no sea 'c' ) //true
o ( 'f' no sea 'f' ) //false
// true || false = true;

entrada = 'q';
boolean continuar = 
( 'q' no sea 'c' ) //true 
o ( 'q' no sea 'f' ) //true
// true || true = true;
```

en otras palabras, tu forma en la que puede ser false es que `entrada` sea `'f'` y `'c'` a la vez lo cual es imposible.

Si quieres que tu programa termine cuando escribes `'o'`  `'f'` tienes que hacer la operación `&&` (`AND`) en la que solo si ambas sentencias se cumplen devuelve true.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que usar &&. Espero te ayude. Un Saludo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        char letra; //declara variable

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //crea objeto Scanner

        //do while loop para validar la letra (loop si pones letra c o f)
        do{

          System.out.println("ecribe una letra que no sea c o f: ");
          letra = scan.next().charAt(0);

        }while(letra != 'c' && letra != 'f'); // aqui el problema. agregue 
        // el operador || y ahora no funciona la validacion (no acepta ninguna letra
        // y sigue repitiendo el loop)


      }
    }
```